# Eliminar duplicados en SQL SERVER priorizando último registro

Tags: sql-server, eliminar-duplicados

Resulta que tengo una tabla en SQL SERVER donde se fueron almacenando a lo largo de los años registros de vehículos. El problema es que ahora estoy intentando "purgar" la información obsoleta de la tabla. Buscando un poco, en la página de Microsoft encontré esta query:

```
DELETE T FROM ( 
SELECT * , DupRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY key_value
          ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
        ) FROM original_table 
) AS TWHERE DupRank > 1
```

Con esto puedo eliminar los duplicados por PATENTE, pero esta query no prioriza el registro más actual.

La tabla es de esta forma:

PATENTE  || CLIENTE || VENCIMIENTO || TELEFONO

ABC123 || CARLOS R... || 2022-01-15 00:00:00 || +5491112345678

ABC123 || CARLOS R... || 2021-02-02 00:00:00 || +5491187654321

ABC123 || CARLOS R... || 2020-01-16 00:00:00 || +5491187654321

Lo que estaría buscando es que solo quede el registro más actual, o sea que la fecha de vencimiento sea lo más cercana a la fecha, pero no sé por donde encarar el query para esta tarea.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Y si ordenas al reves dentro del subquery?

Comment: @gbianchi Como seria exactamente?? Decis meter ROW_NUMER() dentro del over ?? No me quedo muy claro.

Comment: ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) desc? no se si funciona...

Answer (score 1):

En base al ejemplo, el funcionamiento es tal que:

```
Create table dbo.RegVehículos 
(
Patente char(6),
Cliente varchar(20),
Vencimiento datetime,
Telefono varchar(20)
);
GO
Set dateformat ymd
Insert into dbo.RegVehículos
(Patente,Cliente,Vencimiento,Telefono)
Values
('ABC123','CARLOS R','2022-01-15 00:00:00','+5491112345678'),
('ABC123','CARLOS R','2021-02-02 00:00:00','+5491187654321'),
('ABC123','CARLOS R','2020-01-16 00:00:00','+5491187654321'),
('ABC456','JUAN M','2022-01-15 00:00:00','+5491112345111'),
('ABC456','JUAN M','2021-01-15 00:00:00','+5491112345222'),
('ABC456','JUAN M','2020-01-15 00:00:00','+5491112345333'),
('ABC789','ANA G','2020-01-15 00:00:00','+5491112345444');
GO
```

Si la columna que particiona es patente, porque solo queremos un registro de ella y queremos el más moderno, la columna de ordenación será Vencimiento desc, para que nos deje la última.

```
DELETE T FROM ( 
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY Patente
          ORDER BY Vencimiento desc
        ) AS rn
    FROM dbo.RegVehículos 
) AS T
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Resultado

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.RegVehículos;
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!! Me funciono a la perfección. Te agradesco